# How do I select a particular column of a Numpy array read from a CSV?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying:

```
import numpy as np

housing_data = np.loadtxt('Housing.csv', delimiter=',')
print(housing_data)
print(housing_data.shape)
x1 = housing_data[:,:,0]
x2 = housing_data[:,:,1]
y = housing_data[:,:,2]

print(x1)
print(x2)
print(y)
```

My data has shape `(47, 3)` and looks like:

```
[[2.104e+03 3.000e+00 3.999e+05]
 [1.600e+03 3.000e+00 3.299e+05]
 [2.400e+03 3.000e+00 3.690e+05]
 ....
```

I am trying to set the first column to `x1`, the second to `x2` and the third to `y`. But my code doesn't appear to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `housing_data` is a 2D array, and you treat it as a 3D array. Try `x1 = housing_data[:,0]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a dummy *csv file with random data. I would do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# read file using pandas, without header and convert it to numpy arrays
housing_data = pd.read_csv('Housing.csv', header=None).values

# print housing data
print(housing_data)
print(housing_data.shape)

# slice through the data
x1 = housing_data[:,0]
x2 = housing_data[:,1]
y = housing_data[:,2]

print(x1)
print(x2)
print(y)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

selection with Numpy & Python you can use :

```
#Shape (2,2) from top right corner
data[:2,1:]

#Shape bottom row
data[2]

#Shape bottom row
data[2,:]
```

or with conditions :

```
data[data>2]
```

Maybe you could check your .csv file and datatypes:

```
data.astype(float) 
data = np.arange(3, dtype=np.uint8)
```